# Array#each vs. Array#map

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

```
hash = { "d" => [11, 22], "f" => [33, 44, 55] }

# case 1
hash.map {|k,vs| vs.map {|v| "#{k}:#{v}"}}.join(",")
=> "d:11,d:22,f:33,f:44,f:55"

# case 2
hash.map {|k,vs| vs.each {|v| "#{k}:#{v}"}}.join(",")
=> "11,22,33,44,55"
```

only difference is case 1 uses `vs.map`, case 2 uses `vs.each`.

What happened here?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

`Array#each` executes the given block for each element of the array, then returns the array itself.

`Array#map` also executes the given block for each element of the array, but returns a new array whose values are the return values of each iteration of the block.

Example: assume you have an array defined thusly:

```
arr = ["tokyo", "london", "rio"]
```

Then try executing `each`:

```
arr.each { |element| element.capitalize }
# => ["tokyo", "london", "rio"]
```

Note the return value is simply the same array.  The code inside the `each` block gets executed, but the calculated values are not returned; and as the code has no side effects, this example performs no useful work.

In contrast, calling the array's `map` method returns a new array whose elements are the return values of each round of executing the `map` block:

```
arr.map { |element| element.capitalize }
# => ["Tokyo", "London", "Rio"]
```

Comment: Perfect answer to understand. Just a..
Disclaimer: If you overuse the return value of the map function you can potentially waste a lot of memory.

Comment: If your name isn't "Abhishek Tanwar" on Medium, it appears that someone has appropriated your answer and predominantly copied it on Medium. You can view the replicated content here: https://medium.com/@abhishektanwar9596/what-is-the-difference-between-map-and-each-in-ruby-1f2fbb5d5842

Answer (score 35):

The [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) are the same which is adding some confusion to your reverse engineering.

Yes, both iterate over the array (actually, over anything that mixes in [*Enumerable*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html)) but [*map*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) will return an Array composed of the block results while [*each*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) will just return the original Array.

The return value of [*each*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) is just the original array and is rarely used in Ruby code but [*map*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is one of the [most important functional tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

What `map` does is return an array which contains the results of the block or named method that is passed. For example:

```
    2.2.3 :001 > [:how, :now, :brown, :cow].map &:to_s
 => ["how", "now", "brown", "cow"]
```

In this case I didn't pass a block but just a `Symbol`, however `class Symbol` objects have a `to_proc` method which will result in:

```
[:how.to_s, :now.to_s, ...]
```

BTW, you may be having a hard time finding the documentation because *map* is a method in *Enumerable* while *each* (the one method required by the *Enumerable* module) is a method in *Array*.

As a trivia note: the *map* implementation is based on *each*.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a quick demo of how map differs from each

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"];
#Array.map
p a.map {|item| "map_" + item}
#prints ["map_a", "map_b", "map_c"]

#Array.each
p a.each {|item| "map_" + item}
#prints ["a", "b", "c"]
```

You see that map returns `["map_a", "map_b", "map_c"]` whereas each just iterates but returns the original array: `["a", "b", "c"]`.

So each is used for processing an array and map is used to do something with a processed array.

Answer (score 4):

`.each` returns the same array you provided initially:

```
[1,2,3].each { |i| i + 1 }
#=> [1,2,3]
```

`.map` returns a new Array out of the results of each block call:

```
[1,2,3].map { |i| i + 1 }
#=> [2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Array#each method returns same array

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.object_id #70284994490700

b = a.each {|n| n + 2}
p b #[1,2,3,4,5]
b.object_id #70284994490700 <<--- it's the same as a
```

Array#map method returns a new array

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5]
c.object_id #70219117705860

d = c.map {|n| n + 2}
p d #[3,4,5,6,7]
d.object_id #70284994343620  <<---- it's different than c
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use map to a hash, it implicitly casts the hash to an array, so you have

```
[["d", [11, 22]], ["f", [33, 44, 55]]]
```

vs.each{...} only gives you back the last evaluation, which is [11, 22] for ["d", [11, 22]] and [33, 44, 55] for ["f", [33, 44, 55]]. So before the last join, you have

```
[[11, 22], [33, 44, 55]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also to use `map` with bang `map!` that change source array

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. the question is about the difference between `each`, which executes the given block and returns the original array; and `map`, which returns an array with the result of executing the block as values