# How to split up an array into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

```
parsed_data = ["Mike Henry,7/7/87,Oakland,831 123-2758", "David Jordan,12/30/92,Bangkok,831 229-1234", "Matt Rosen,5/21/89,Seattle,925 518-9933"]
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
[["Mike Henry", "7/7/87", "Oakland", "831 123-2758"],["David Jordan", "12/30/92", "Bangkok", "831 229-1234"],["Matt Rosen", "5/21/89", "Seattle", "925 518-9933"]]
```

I have tried

```
parsed_data = parsed_data.each do |file|
  file.split(",")
end
```

but it returns my original array.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might be a duplicate depending upon your interpretation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254128/arrayeach-vs-arraymap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Enumerable#map`, because `Enumerable#each` will just iterate through the items, but `#map` will create a new array from the return value of the block:

```
parsed_data.map { |data| data.split(',') }
```

Comment: ahh I totally forgot how to use map.  Thanks a lot!