# Inner json objects not rendering Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

First model:

```
class AdPlace < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_ads, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_ads, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

   def ad_places_json
    self.as_json(
    include: {
        user_ads: {

        }
    })
  end
end
```

Second Model:

```
class UserAd < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ad_place
end
```

From my controller I am trying to get all AdPlaces having all UserAds.
So my method of controller is following:

```
 def get_ads
      ad_places = AdPlace.includes(:user_ads).where(user_id: @current_user.id)
      render json: {
          ad_places: ad_places.each {|ad| ad.ad_places_json},
          message: ['success']
      },
          status: :ok
    end
```

**The above function renders all AdPlaces but UserAds.**
The SELECT query on server is the following:

```
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  AdPlace Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "ad_places".* FROM "ad_places"
  UserAd Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "user_ads".* FROM "user_ads" WHERE "user_ads"."ad_place_id" IN (1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
```

Everything seems perfect to me, I am confused where am I making mistake.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `each` to `map`:

```
ad_places.map {|ad| ad.ad_places_json}
```

[`Array#each vs. Array#map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254128/arrayeach-vs-arraymap)