# Active Model Serilazer returns default JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have a Active Model Serializer class like this

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :activities
 def activities
    object.activities.each do |activity|
      post_json(activity) if activity.class.name == 'Post'
      like_json(activity) if activity.class.name == 'PostLike'
      comments_json(activity) if activity.class.name == 'PostComment'
    end
  end

  def post_json(post)
    {
        type: 'share',
        user: post.user_id,
        user_name: post.user.display_name,
        user_image_thumb: post.user.profile.image.thumb.url,
        id: post.id,
        created_at: post.created_at
    } if post
  end

  def like_json(like)
    {
        type: 'like',
        user: like.user_id,
        user_name: like.user.display_name,
        user_image_thumb: like.user.profile.image.thumb.url,
        id: like.id,
        created_at: like.created_at
    } if like
  end

  def comments_json(comment)
    {
        type: 'comment',
        user: comment.user_id,
        user_name: comment.user.display_name,
        user_image_thumb: comment.user.profile.image.thumb.url,
        id: comment.id,
        created_at: comment.created_at,
        content: comment.content
    } if comment
  end
end
```

But the response always returns the default response object and doesnot contain the fields from the json builder methods.

```
"activities": [
      {
        "id": 40,
        "user_id": 22,
        "post_id": 8,
        "created_at": "2016-04-22T07:29:26.210Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-04-22T07:29:26.210Z"
      }
]
```

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `each` to `map`:

```
 def activities
    object.activities.map do |activity|
      post_json(activity) if activity.class.name == 'Post'
      like_json(activity) if activity.class.name == 'PostLike'
      comments_json(activity) if activity.class.name == 'PostComment'
    end
  end
```

[`Array#each vs. Array#map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254128/arrayeach-vs-arraymap)

Comment: @SoorajChandu read the link 
[`Array#each vs. Array#map`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254128/arrayeach-vs-arraymap)

Comment: Thanks you ..i was unaware of this

Comment: @SoorajChandu If this answer is satisfying, please accept it. :)