# Ruby Hash Mutability

Tags: ruby

In Ruby (1.9.3) why does this code not change the array values:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
arr.each do |e|
  e = 'new string'
end
```

While this code *does* change the hashes in *item-b*:

```
hashh = {
  'item-a' => 1,
  'item-b' => [
    {'id'=>'a','name'=>'name-a'},
    {'id'=>'b', 'name'=>'name-b'}
  ]
}

hashh['item-b'].each do |e|
  e['name'] = 'new-name'
end
```

I know that I can use *map* on the array to change the values by why does *each* allow me to change the hashes but *not* the array values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array#each vs. Array#map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254128/arrayeach-vs-arraymap)

Comment: `Array#each` allows you to change values: `arr.each { |e| e.replace 'new string' }`.

Answer (score 2):

The first case has only local variable assignment:

```
arr.each do |e|
  e = 'new string'
end
```

Yet the second is actually using [Hash#[]=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) which is a method. `hash[:key] = "val"` is syntactic sugar for `hash.send(:[]=, :key, "val")` in other words, and inside that method the actual updating of the hash happens via C code.

Comment: I kind of disagree with the "synactic sugar". In that sense, `foo.bar(true)` is syntactic sugar for `foo.send(:bar, true)`, which has nothing to do with the question. The point is that `[]=` is a method, whereas variable assignment is not.

Comment: @Max fair point, I guess it'd be more accurate to say it's sugar for `hash.[]=(:foo, "bar")` (forgot that it was a public method)

Answer (score 2):

> In Ruby (1.9.3) why does this code not change the array values:
>
> ```
> arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
> arr.each do |e|
>   e = 'new string'
> end
> ```

This code never does anything with the array values. Why would it change them? It simply assigns a string to the local variable `e`, which falls out of scope immediately, so the entire thing is a no-op.

> While this code *does* change the hashes in *item-b*:
>
> ```
> hashh = {
>   'item-a' => 1,
>   'item-b' => [
>     {'id'=>'a','name'=>'name-a'},
>     {'id'=>'b', 'name'=>'name-b'}
>   ]
> }
>
> hashh['item-b'].each do |e|
>   e['name'] = 'new-name'
> end
> ```

`Hash#[]=` is a method which mutates the hash. Since you call a method which mutates the value (which is a hash), the value is mutated.

> I know that I can use *map* on the array to change the values

`map` does *not* change the values. It returns a *new* array. (Well, obviously, you *can* change the values in a `map`, but that's not what it was designed for, and you shouldn't do it.)

> by why does *each* allow me to change the hashes but *not* the array values?

`each` doesn't do anything here. In the second case, you call a method which mutates the value, ergo, the value gets mutated. In the first case, you *don't* call a method which mutates the value; in fact, you don't call any method *at all*. Ergo, the value doesn't get mutated.