# How to get data in grape api? rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I have these models:

```
#Poll
class Poll < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :questions
end
#Question
class Question < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :poll
end
```

And the Question model has a boolean field named "hide", when is true, the question does not show in the API's JSON.

Then, I wanna send in a JSON with Grape gem, all polls, with all questions for that poll, something like this:

```
{Polls =>
    {id: 1, name: "poll_name", questions => {
        {id: 1, question: "question 1"}}},
    {id: 2, name: "poll_name", questions => {
        {id: 2, question: "question 2"},
        {id: 3, question: "question 3"}}
}
```

But when I

```
#api.rb
module AccountStory
class API < ::Grape::API
    version 'v1', using: :path
    format :json
    prefix :api

    #api/v1/account_stories
    resource :account_stories do
        desc 'Return list of polls'
        get do
            Poll.all.each do |poll|
            {"Poll" => {"id" => poll.id, "name" => poll.name, "questions" => poll.questions}}
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I execute the server, it return this:

```
0
  id    1
  uuid  "5b65d39ea89db96a8ab89fd3"
  name  "Poll 1"
  created_at    "2018-08-04T16:26:06.218Z"
  updated_at    "2018-08-04T16:26:06.218Z"
```

I have in the database only 1 poll, but the script does not get me the questions in that poll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get do # ---v
  Poll.all.each do |poll|
    {"Poll" => {"id" => poll.id, "name" => poll.name, "questions" => poll.questions}}
  end
end
```

This looks like your issue, you're using `each` instead of `collect` / `map`:

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5254192) for an answer that explains the difference between the 2 methods.