# Rubocop Lint/Void: Literal used in void context in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I have this code, and rubocop tell me "Rubocop Lint/Void: Literal used in void context". How can I modify this problem and fix this message. Thanks.

```rb
e.messages.map.each { |key, message| { field: key, message: message } }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with using `map` and `each` altogether. Yes, you can use both but there is no need to use both here.
Either you should use:

`e.messages.each { |key, message| { field: key, message: message } }`

Or you should use:

`e.messages.map { |key, message| { field: key, message: message } }`

The basic difference is that `each` returns the original array whereas `map` returns the resultant array.

Here is the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254128/arrayeach-vs-arraymap) between `map` & `each` explained very well.