# How to convert a comma-delimited string into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm trying to make a array out of a string and then get rid of the quotes surrounding the strings.

This is what I tried:

```
hg = "'Erra', 'Erra-Network', 'Discovery'".split(",")
hg2 = hg.each { |n| n.delete_prefix("'").delete_suffix("'") }
print(hg2)
```

but doesn't work.

Output:

```
["'Erra'", " 'Erra-Network'", " 'Discovery'"]
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: an array without the single quotes

Comment: change `each` to `map` and try again

Comment: `"'Erra', 'Erra-Network', 'Discovery'"` – where does that string come from?

Comment: @Mefistofeles : You calculate inside your block a new string, and then throw it away. You never actually modify one of the array elements. Look up in the docs the difference between `delete_prefix` and `delete_prefix!`.

Comment: Rather than splitting the string, then removing the quotes from each element of the resulting array it makes more sense to remove the quotes from the string before splitting it. If `str = "'Erra', 'Erra-Network', 'Discovery'"`, then `str.delete("'").split(", ") #=> ["Erra", "Erra-Network", "Discovery"] `.  If there may be zero or two or more spaces after each comma, write `str.delete("'").split(/, */)`. The regular expression `/, */` reads, "match a comma followed by zero or more (`*`) spaces".

Comment: Please don't say things like "doesn't work." We need to know _WHY_ it doesn't. If you don't tell us we sometimes can guess, but too often the reason is because it doesn't meet your needs/goals and we have no idea what those are. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: Your string is suspicious. We rarely see strings like that if we've handled our input right. I suspect this is an XY problem where you're asking about the wrong thing; you should be asking about how to properly gather the data prior to needing to clean it and parse it. See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)".

Answer (score 4):

Try `map` instead of `each`, it will return a new updated Array:

```
hg = "'Erra', 'Erra-Network', 'Discovery'".split(",")
hg2 = hg.map { |n| n.delete_prefix("'").delete_suffix("'") }
print(hg2)
```

`each` will execute for each element in the Array, but will then return the original unmodified Array. `map` actually returns the modified Array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5254192/44733

Comment: A space in the delimiter is required in order for this solution to work `split(", ")`.

Answer (score 1):

You're working on `hg` but then printing `hg2` to check if the operation succeeded. Although that's not the problem, it may lead to confusion.

Also, as you're using `delete_prefix` and `delete_suffix` in their non-destructive versions, the changes applied return a new object, which isn't "persisted" anywhere.

If you want to see the changes that that produces you can use their destructive version `delete_prefix!`, `delete_suffix!`:

```
hg2 = hg.each do |n|
  n.delete_prefix!("'")
  n.delete_suffix!("'")
end

hg # ["Erra", " 'Erra-Network", " 'Discovery"]
```

Or rather use map and yield the result of every operation into a new object:

```
hg2 = hg.map { |n| n.delete_prefix("'").delete_suffix("'") }

p hg2 # ["Erra", " 'Erra-Network", " 'Discovery"]
```

Although this results in `["Erra", " 'Erra-Network", " 'Discovery"]` and doesn't go according to the title of the question *"delete the quotes surrounding the strings"*.

Comment: Aaah I got it, totally.

Comment: As per the last comment, the title is a bit misleading as it doesn't correspond itself with what's being shown in the code. The fact of using delete_prefix and/or delete_suffix doesn't mean you're going to delete the quotes surrounding strings.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too difficult. I'd do this:

```
hg = "'Erra', 'Erra-Network', 'Discovery'"

hg.delete(" '").split(',') # => ["Erra", "Erra-Network", "Discovery"]
```

[`delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-delete) is doing the clean-up, which should be done before trying to [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split) the string.

`delete_prefix` and `delete_suffix` are useful methods, but not when processing strings you're parsing because they force you into iteratively processing the sub-strings. `delete` does the entire string in one step, which is faster.

If I was going to iterate, I'd do something like this:

```
hg.split(/, */).map { |s| s[1..-2] } # => ["Erra", "Erra-Network", "Discovery"]
```

which takes advantage of `split` being able to take a regular expression to automatically break on a comma followed by any number of spaces.
Basically you'll trying to parse a mangled CSV record, so you should use the [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) class. The documentation has many [examples for parsing](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Reading) records:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.parse(hg.delete("' ")).flatten # => ["Erra", "Erra-Network", "Discovery"]
```

CSV has many options available for handling odd variations of delimiters and quoted strings, so study the documentation if you want to go that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSV to get your result:

```
require 'csv'

string = "'Erra', 'Erra-Network', 'Discovery'"
result = CSV.parse_line(string, col_sep: ', ', quote_char: "'")
#=> ["Erra", "Erra-Network", "Discovery"]
```

Note that the above assumes that the separator is `', '`. This means that a comma must always be followed by a space.